# How do I add Razorpay button in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, sapper, svelte-component

```
<div class="donate">Click On Below Button To Donate</div>
  <br />
  <form>
    <script
      src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js"
      data-payment_button_id="pl_GfQFdLtveYUasE"
      async>
    </script>
  </form>
  <div class="thanks">Thank You For Your Generous Donations</div>
</div>
```

It is showing in the dev server while debugging but after building it's not showing

Comment: It's because of SPA loading, probably. You might be better off by placing the script in the header of your full page and check the documentation to dynamically 'load' the button via JS. A script like this works for static pages but Svelte is an SPA and loads differently.